# Not getting sorted Data back when querying on LSI, with a fake partition key which is equal in all items

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I have a dynamoDb table for storing `user` and their `roleType` with possible values of `['PO','CCM','SU']`, in this table the partition key i have set is a fake attribute called `fakeKey`, the value for this `fakeKey` is same for every Item in table, i have set a local Secondary Index for which the sort Key is `roleType`, the intention is to get all of the data sorted on `roleType`, but it does not seem to be happening. Below is the node js code for querying the data.

```
    dynamoDB.query({
      TableName: process.env.TABLE_USER_V2 as string,
      indexName: sortBy,
      ScanIndexForward:ascending,
      KeyConditionExpression: "fakeKey = :fake",
      ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":fake": 'fake',
      },
    },
     (err: any, data: any) => {
      if (err) reject(err);
      else {
        resolve(data);
      }
      console.log("scanResult--", data);
    });
```

but the data i am getting is of random order instead, it is not ordered based on roleType at all.

PS: - i have created total 5 LSI with `fakeKey` as partition key, with sort keys shown below

```
createdBy (String)
createdDate (Number)
email (String)  
modifiedDate (Number)   
roleType (String)
```

below is the expanded array i am getting from query result, as u can see it is not sorted while fakeKey is fake.

```
(17) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
{roleType: 'CCM', createdDate: 1667914128541, modifiedDate: 1667914128541, email: 'Candra Aubry@se.com', fakeKey: 'fake', …}
1:
{roleType: 'PO', createdDate: 1667914128445, modifiedDate: 1667914128445, email: 'Charlot Clair@se.com', fakeKey: 'fake', …}
2:
{roleType: 'CCM', createdDate: 1667914128500, modifiedDate: 1667914128500, email: 'Dagmar Doretta@se.com', fakeKey: 'fake', …}
3:
{roleType: 'CCM', createdDate: 1667914128507, modifiedDate: 1667914128507, email: 'Deny Helsa@se.com', fakeKey: 'fake', …}
4:
{roleType: 'CCM', createdDate: 1667914128454, modifiedDate: 1667914128454, email: 'Druci Beitris@se.com', fakeKey: 'fake', …}
5:
{roleType: 'CCM', createdDate: 1667914128568, modifiedDate: 1667914128568, email: 'Eirena Mariquilla@se.com', fakeKey: 'fake', …}
6:
{roleType: 'CCM', createdDate: 1667914128417, modifiedDate: 1667914128417, email: 'Evangeline Marquita@se.com', fakeKey: 'fake', …}
7:
{roleType: 'CCM', createdDate: 1667914128018, modifiedDate: 1667914128018, email: 'Eve Eryn@se.com', fakeKey: 'fake', …}
8:
{roleType: 'SU', createdDate: 1667832856296, modifiedDate: 1667832856296, lastModifiedBy: 'ADM694685', email: 'harit@se.com', …}
9:
{roleType: 'CCM', createdDate: 1667914128439, modifiedDate: 1667914128439, email: 'Isabelita Miriam@se.com', fakeKey: 'fake', …}
10:
{roleType: 'CCM', createdDate: 1667914128394, modifiedDate: 1667914128394, email: 'Keely Breanne@se.com', fakeKey: 'fake', …}
11:
{roleType: 'CCM', createdDate: 1667914128475, modifiedDate: 1667914128475, email: 'Leyla Barbaraanne@se.com', fakeKey: 'fake', …}
12:
{roleType: 'CCM', createdDate: 1667914128518, modifiedDate: 1667914128518, email: 'Lucie Rena@se.com', fakeKey: 'fake', …}
```

here is the describe table,

```
{
  "Table": {
    "AttributeDefinitions": [
      {
        "AttributeName": "admId",
        "AttributeType": "S"
      },
      {
        "AttributeName": "createdBy",
        "AttributeType": "S"
      },
      {
        "AttributeName": "createdDate",
        "AttributeType": "N"
      },
      {
        "AttributeName": "email",
        "AttributeType": "S"
      },
      {
        "AttributeName": "fakeKey",
        "AttributeType": "S"
      },
      {
        "AttributeName": "modifiedDate",
        "AttributeType": "N"
      },
      {
        "AttributeName": "name",
        "AttributeType": "S"
      },
      {
        "AttributeName": "roleType",
        "AttributeType": "S"
      }
    ],
    "TableName": "e-system_users_roles_v3-dmsm_data-dev",
    "KeySchema": [
      {
        "AttributeName": "fakeKey",
        "KeyType": "HASH"
      },
      {
        "AttributeName": "name",
        "KeyType": "RANGE"
      }
    ],
    "TableStatus": "ACTIVE",
    "CreationDateTime": {
    },
    "ProvisionedThroughput": {
      "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
      "ReadCapacityUnits": 0,
      "WriteCapacityUnits": 0
    },
    "TableSizeBytes": 2052,
    "ItemCount": 17,
    "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/e-system_users_roles_v3-dmsm_data-dev",
    "TableId": "089c5a70-6819-47be-85c0-7e612faccf56",
    "BillingModeSummary": {
      "BillingMode": "PAY_PER_REQUEST",
      "LastUpdateToPayPerRequestDateTime": {
      }
    },
    "LocalSecondaryIndexes": [
      {
        "IndexName": "modifiedDate-index",
        "KeySchema": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "fakeKey",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
          },
          {
            "AttributeName": "modifiedDate",
            "KeyType": "RANGE"
          }
        ],
        "Projection": {
          "ProjectionType": "ALL"
        },
        "IndexSizeBytes": 2017,
        "ItemCount": 17,
        "IndexArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/e-system_users_roles_v3-dmsm_data-dev/index/modifiedDate-index"
      },
      {
        "IndexName": "createdDate-index",
        "KeySchema": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "fakeKey",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
          },
          {
            "AttributeName": "createdDate",
            "KeyType": "RANGE"
          }
        ],
        "Projection": {
          "ProjectionType": "ALL"
        },
        "IndexSizeBytes": 2017,
        "ItemCount": 17,
        "IndexArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/e-system_users_roles_v3-dmsm_data-dev/index/createdDate-index"
      },
      {
        "IndexName": "roleType-index",
        "KeySchema": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "fakeKey",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
          },
          {
            "AttributeName": "roleType",
            "KeyType": "RANGE"
          }
        ],
        "Projection": {
          "ProjectionType": "ALL"
        },
        "IndexSizeBytes": 2017,
        "ItemCount": 17,
        "IndexArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/e-system_users_roles_v3-dmsm_data-dev/index/roleType-index"
      },
      {
        "IndexName": "createdBy-index",
        "KeySchema": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "fakeKey",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
          },
          {
            "AttributeName": "createdBy",
            "KeyType": "RANGE"
          }
        ],
        "Projection": {
          "ProjectionType": "ALL"
        },
        "IndexSizeBytes": 147,
        "ItemCount": 1,
        "IndexArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/e-system_users_roles_v3-dmsm_data-dev/index/createdBy-index"
      },
      {
        "IndexName": "email-index",
        "KeySchema": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "fakeKey",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
          },
          {
            "AttributeName": "email",
            "KeyType": "RANGE"
          }
        ],
        "Projection": {
          "ProjectionType": "ALL"
        },
        "IndexSizeBytes": 2017,
        "ItemCount": 17,
        "IndexArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/e-system_users_roles_v3-dmsm_data-dev/index/email-index"
      }
    ],
    "GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [
      {
        "IndexName": "admId-email-index",
        "KeySchema": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "admId",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
          },
          {
            "AttributeName": "email",
            "KeyType": "RANGE"
          }
        ],
        "Projection": {
          "ProjectionType": "ALL"
        },
        "IndexStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
          "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0,
          "ReadCapacityUnits": 0,
          "WriteCapacityUnits": 0
        },
        "IndexSizeBytes": 2017,
        "ItemCount": 17,
        "IndexArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:table/e-system_users_roles_v3-dmsm_data-dev/index/admId-email-index"
      }
    ],
    "TableClassSummary": {
      "TableClass": "STANDARD"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: LSI have the same partition key as the table.  Do you mean Global Secondary Index (GSI)?

Comment: Hi @Charles, I have created LSIs only, i was under the impression that LSI creates a different set of records and keep them sorted based on sortKey, and GSI is needed when i want to query on different partition Key, i just started on dynamoDB this week only, so pls correct me if i am assuming something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are storing everything with a fixed value: `fake` and are using an LSI to sort the data based upon `roleType` then you should be returned all data in the LSI ordered by `roleType`.

I would ensure you are reading from the correct LSI when wanting to order by `roleType`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html#LSI.Querying

I would suggest hard-coding the values into your params for now, just to be sure you are not picking up other values at run-time.

Should that fail, please provide the output of `DescribeTable` for your table so I can inspect the configuration.

While the above directly answers your question I avoided the fact that using a single value as a partition key is not scalable at all, especially when using 5 LSIs. You cap your writr throughput to 200 RPS assuming each item is less than 1KB.

Comment: thanks @LeeHannigan, do you have any other approach in mind ?, actually the requirement is to provide a sort along with pagination on all of the columns for the above data using DynamoDB. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks again for looking :-D

Comment: i have checked as u asked and at runtime the value is as expected ie ```roleType-index``` , but the order is still random, i have updated the describe Table in the question itself.

Comment: Hi, it was very frustrating, we made a Typo, instead of ```indexName``` it was supposed to be ```IndexName```